# Kotlin nested when

Tags: kotlin

I have the next code. As you may see there are 3 `when` one inside another. Is it possible to flatten this code? I'm thinking about some wrapper but cannot get it. For now the only solution that I see is to move each when to the `fun` like `processFirstWhen` etc. Perhaps there is a cleaner solution. Any help appreciated.

```
when (val result = callback.invoke()) {
            is DataCompletable.Success -> DomainCompletable.Success
            is DataCompletable.Error ->
                when (result.error) {
                    is DataError.Unauthorized ->
                        when (tokenMixIn.refresh()) {
                            is DomainCompletable.Success -> execute(
                                currentNumberOfRetries + 1,
                                callback
                            )
                            is DomainCompletable.Error -> DomainCompletable.Error(DomainError.RefreshFailed)
                        }
                    else -> DomainCompletable.Error(result.error.mapToDomain())
                }
```

Comment: Are DomainCompletable, DataCompletable and DataError from a library?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no, they are my classes

Comment: It looks like your class hierarchy and design is forcing the nested statements, but I can't suggest anything without knowing how it all works.

Comment: Can we create two objects out of this? I mean one object responsible for callback invocation and other handling the error scenario in your case. The error object will only be invoked with certain preconditions I am talking about these tokenMixIn.refresh(). Depending on this value I am not sure what it does but based on these value only it will move to the next layer.

Answer (score 2):

Easy! But not using `when`.

What I suppose is to replace it with flat hierarchy of `if`'s.

Like this:

```
val result = callback.invoke()
if(result is DataCompletable.Success) return DomainCompletable.Success
val error = result.error
if(error !is DataError.Unauthorized) return DomainCompletable.Error(result.error.mapToDomain())
val refreshResult = tokenMixIn.refresh()
if(refreshResult is DomainCompletable.Error) return DomainCompletable.Error(DomainError.RefreshFailed)
execute(currentNumberOfRetries + 1, callback)
```

Key aspect here is short-circuitness. We return result as soon as possible. But also we achieve flatter and easier to understand code.

Comment: This is much less readable than nested when in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Nested when structures are difficult to understand because you can easily confuse the cases of an inner when as belonging to an outer statement. Therefore nested when statements should be avoided.

Specifically, you should structure your code to avoid the need for nested when statements, but if you cannot, then consider moving the inner when to another function.

```
    when(val result =callback.invoke())
            {
                is DataCompletable.Success -> DomainCompletable.Success
                is DataCompletable.Error ->
                    errorCallBack(result.error)
            }
    
            

    fun errorCallBack(val error:Error) {
    
                when(error) {
                    is DataError.Unauthorized ->
                            when(tokenMixIn.refresh()) {
                        is DomainCompletable.Success -> execute(
                                currentNumberOfRetries + 1,
                                callback
                        )
                        is DomainCompletable.Error -> DomainCompletable.Error(DomainError.RefreshFailed)
                    }
                                else ->DomainCompletable.Error(result.error.mapToDomain())
                }
    
            }
```